# In WinRT how to check if the application has the resources?

Tags: windows-runtime

I am using the following code to get the resources

```
 ResourceLoader manager = null;
 manager = new ResourceLoader("Resources");
```

but it shows the  "ResourceMap not found" exception.

My question is how to check if the application has the resources ? If the application is not have the resources means i have to skip it.

Comment: Can you just wrap it in a `try/catch`?

Comment: I used that also but still the exception cause.Please give another solution

Comment: @Jai that is the solution. Show the code that you are using with your try/catch

Comment: @MarkHall It actually does matter what kind of exception is being thrown. If it's a managed exception, try/catch will work. If it's a native exception, it will bypass the managed try/catch, but he shouldn't be able to see it so readily unless he's also using the native debugger.